# Как сделать бота для роблокс по типу Mineflayer JS

Tags: бот

Существует библиотека Mineflayer.js
для создания Майнкрафт ботов. Как создать что-то подобное, но в роблокс?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Бота в роблокс можно сделать, используя библиотеку `noblox.js`.